# Convert string into numeric and change period to comma seperator sas

Tags: sas

I have a string called `weight`  that is `85.5`

I would like to convert it into a numeric `85,5` and replace the decimal seperator with a comma using SAS.

So far I am using this (messy) two step approach

```
weight_num= (weight*1);
format weight_num COMMAX13.2;
```

How can this be achieved in a less clumpsy way??

Comment: i am not sure what you want to do. If weight is a character variable, it will always stay a character variable inside a datastep, you would have to build a temporary variable, drop the char-weight, and rename the temp variable to weight in next datastep : 
`data x; 
set yourdata; 
format weight_num COMMAX13.2; 
weight_num=weight; 
drop weight; 
run; 
data yourdata; 
set x(rename=(weight_num=weight)); 
run;`

Comment: @kl78: great, so I do not have to convert a character into a numeric first before I apply a new format. (I edited my question for clarification)

Comment: Do you want to convert your character variable to a numeric variable? or another character variable?  Also what do you want to do with values that cannot be translated to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code is the recommended method of changing a variable type.

Another way is `transtrn` function to replace the . with a comma. This is only a good method if you don't plan to do any calculations on the values.

```
data have;
set sashelp.class;
keep name weight:;
weight_char=put(weight, 8.1);
run;


data want;
set have;
weight_char=transtrn(weight_char, ".", ",");
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change it so that commas are used for decimal point instead of periods then why not just use a simple character substitution.  Do you also want to change thousands separator from comma to period?  `TRANSLATE()` is good for that.

```
weight = translate(weight,',.','.,');
```

If you want to convert it to a number then use the `INPUT()` function rather than forcing SAS to convert for you.

```
weight_num = input(weight,comma32.);
```

You can then attach whatever format you want to the new numeric variable.